# Regarding Ubuntu 13.10 upgrade

Tags: installation, 13.10

I am planning to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (both fresh as I am buying new laptop) by doing separate installation partition for both OS. I have two ques:

1) For Ubuntu 13.10 it says 9 months support. Does it mean I can't be able to use after 9 months?

2) If I have to update in future to 14.XX LTS system, then will my Windows 7 be affected? I don't want to loose any data and don't want to do fresh installation in future.
Please help me. I am going to use Ubuntu first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu on a separate partition you should be able to re-install at any time without upsetting windows at all. So definitely a good idea to partition the drive out properly.

Split your linux partition into three with root or '/' with about 20 to 50 gb, a swap space with about 5 to 10 and the rest as /home, for your own programmes and data. This will make Ubuntu more stable all round.

13.10 is a development release - it's about doing development for the next stable release, which will be 14.04, so it isn't a good idea to depend on 13.10 long-term.

Your best bet is to install 13.10 and upgrade to 14.04 next April. Then you can either stick with that for the next five years or carry on upgrading every six months to make sure you have the most modern linux kernel and features installed.

If you have your linux partition nicely set up you have a better chance of trouble free upgrades in the future too!